# how insert into product table having hierarchical categories

Tags: mysql, database-design

i have a table category made up of adjacent list model:

```
id      name        parent_id
1   Clothing        0
2   Books           0
3   Computers       0
4   Mobiles         0
5   Movies          0
6   Music           0
7   Mens            1
8   Shirts          7
9   Formal Trousers 7
10  Jeans           7
```

and product_category table:

```
product_id fk
category_id fk
parent_id
```

and have a product table

```
product_id
category_id
parent_id
prod_name
genre
unit price
image
```

how can i insert the products in table that has link to the parent-id and in-turn it has link to category. so that i can retrieve the products from parent_id and categories.
and should i define parent_id as a primary key..
help appreciated..thanks in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert products into table in hierarchical relationship of category and parent in adjacent list model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919592/insert-products-into-table-in-hierarchical-relationship-of-category-and-parent-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am correct I understand that, you need to retrieve the data in reverse order. Such as, parent_id + category_id -> product_id as well as product_id -> parent_id + category_id.

I hope you did the most, I just suggest you to use the SQL 'where' clause to retrieve the data from end.

I even thought to use the PK of category, parent and product in each table but after some research I found I can retrieve the data without changing the database design.