# Insert products into table in hierarchical relationship of category and parent in adjacent list model

Tags: mysql, database-design, adjacency-list-model

i have a table category made up of adjacency list model:

```
id  name             parent_id
------------------------------
1   Clothing         0
2   Books            0
3   Computers        0
4   Mobiles          0
5   Movies           0
6   Music            0
7   Mens             1
8   Shirts           7
9   Formal Trousers  7
10  Jeans            7
```

and product_category table:

```
product_id fk
category_id fk
parent_id
```

and have a product table:

```
product_id
category_id
parent_id
prod_name
genre
unit price
image
```

how can i insert the products in table that has link to the parent-id and in-turn it has link to category. so that i can retrieve the products from parent_id and categories.
and should i define parent_id as a primary key..
help appreciated..thanks in advance..

Comment: Given this data set, what should the result set (i.e., the contents of `product`) look like?

Comment: I just noticed you've posted a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14919370/533120). Never do that! If you need to raise the "visibility" of your question, gather enough reputation then start a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties).

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic i have just started to use stack overflow.. the original question was posted by me.. i just wanted to make some adjustment to that.. sorry for that..

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic please tell me how you created a foreign key of parent_ID with category_ID as primary key and foreign key of parent_ID with product_ID.. please help..

Comment: @VishalTorne _"i just wanted to make some adjustment to that"_ -  Simply use the "edit" link (at the bottom of your question) for that.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: when i insert into product like this: (prod_ID parent_ID prod_Name price  image) Values ( 1,7'Dominoe shirts'349.00,BLOB) it gives me an error:ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`shopping`.`products`, CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_ID`) REFERENCES `products` (`product_ID`)) .. please help me.. thanks in advance..

Comment: @VishalTorne The error message says exactly what's wrong: you are trying to insert a value in the "child" table that doesn't exist in the "parent" table.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: this is my last question to you sir.. can make `product.parent_ID` to reference `category.category_ID` so that while retrieving it i may be able to get the products from the `parent_id` which is inside `category` table. thank you for help.. and thank you for tolerating me.. appreciated your help.. thanks

Comment: @VishalTorne _"can make product.parent_ID to reference category.category_ID"_ - you can, but that doesn't necessarily mean you should. As I already explained, it all boils down to what kind of relationship you need (1:N or M:N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the relationship between products and categories is M:N, and both categories and products form a hierarchy (independent from one another), your model should look like:

**category:**

```
category_id PK
parent_id FK -> category.category_id
(other fields...)
```

**product:**

```
product_id PK
parent_id FK -> product.product_id
(other fields...)
```

**product_category:**

```
product_id FK -> product.product_id
category_id FK -> category.category_id
PK (product_id, category_id)
```

---

I'm not quite sure what you mean by: *"how can i insert the products in table that has link to the parent-id and in-turn it has link to category"*? Assuming you know the id of the parent product and the id of the category, you can just:

```
INSERT INTO product (product_id, parent_id, other fields...)
VALUES (whatever, known parent id, other values...)
```

And then connect it to the category:

```
INSERT INTO product_category (product_id, category_id)
VALUES (what you inserted above, known category id)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.. really appreciated, but did you describe parent_ID as foreign key in all three tables.. i have seen that a column to become an foreign key it has has to be declared as primary key in some table..

Comment: @VishalTorne _"column to become an foreign key it has has to be declared as primary key in some table"_ - FK itself doesn't have to be a key, it just needs to _reference_ a (primary or alternate) key. In my model: the `category.parent_id` references the `category` tables's PK, the `product.parent_id` references the `product`'s PK, the `product_category.product_id` references the `product`'s PK and the `product_category.category_id` references the `category`'s PK.

Comment: i am sounding silly but .. why `parent_ID` is referencing `product_ID`of `product` table, it should reference `category.category_ID` PK , how `parent_ID` and `products.product_ID` are related.. and how it will help me retrieve the products.. please help.. appreciating your help..

Comment: @VishalTorne It's all about your requirements and **you** are the one who has to define them - I can only tell you how to model them in the database **after** you do. **If** you need M:N relationship, **then** you need the "junction" (aka. "link") table `product_category` and do **not** need `product.category_id`. **If** you need product hierarchy which is independent from category hierarchy, **then** you need `product.parent_id`. Please re-read my answer and you'll notice I predicated it on these assumptions. If these assumptions are wrong - you have to tell us!

Comment: @ Branko Dimitrijevic i think i made a mistake.. "how can i insert the products in table that has link to the parent-id and in-turn it has link to category" i was just referring that products table include many products not in hierarchy, suppose my shirt category inside a parent **mens** has 15 products, so i just want to state that there are many products in the shirts parent ,so i can't refer it to the product_ID as there are many products.. i just wanted to associate parent_id that has link to the category.parent_ID so that I could retrieve all products on the basis of category.parent_ID.